# How to compare characters inside string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-comparison

I'm a beginner and I have a question. Is there any possibility to compare characters inside strings?

I made a function:

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    text1 = text.split()
    a = ''
    count = 0
    for a in text1:
        for char in enumerate(a):
            if char[0] == char[1]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Result:

```
>>> animal_crackers('Spam Spam')
>>> False
```

The logic is that I'm trying to split a string consisting of two words. Then I set those words with 1st "for" cycle and then I'm trying to get inside the string with the 2nd and this "char in enumerate(a)".

It should return True if both words start with the same letter.

This is basically not working so I'm wondering. Can you give me an advice and not ready code? Or maybe you can tell me where's mistake.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this code is supposed to do, but it seems like you're trying to write a very verbose version of `return text1[0] == text1[1]`?

Comment: Can you clarify please? First you state you want to compare characters inside a string. Next you state the function should return True is the words start with the same character.  These are **very** different things.  Please clarify and provide some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at Levensthein distance for strings. This is really basic, but both a good lesson for starters and a reasonable method of comparing typography.

Answer (score 0):

While strings are not the same as lists, their elements can be accessed like lists.

```
salami = 'Salami'
spam = 'Spam'
cheese = 'Cheese'

salami[0] == spam[0] # True
salami[0] == cheese[0] # False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need:

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    text1 = text.split()
    for i in range(len(text1)-1):
        if text1[i][0] == text1[i+1][0]:
             print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
    return
```

Comment: how this for i in range (len(text1)-1) works? and what for?

Answer (score 0):

I can see where the mistake is and it is at the "enumerate(a)". when you use enumerate it will return a pair like for the first iteration it will give `(0, 'S')` i.e. `char[0] = 0` and `char[1]='S'` so `char[0] == char[1]` is `False` and they are different data types. Instead try indexing like a list since `text1.split()` will return list. I hope it helps.